# Erlang - automatically adding debugging/tracing statements to code

Tags: debugging, erlang, trace

**Problem**: Many Erlang modules with [Common Test](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/basics_chapter.html) suites need to be run on daily basis to check if no new bugs were introduced. For those cases when bugs are introduced, we want to find the exact place and possibly the state of program before test case failure. Because of time constraints debugging using dbg or other debug tools is not possible. Usually test suites contain some print statements that allow to somehow pinpoint whereabouts of bug, but their frequency is too low to be effective. Usually the debug statements are added manually, but it takes time.

**Proposed solution**:
I wanted to take code of given testcase or whole Common Test suite and create at least printout with line number and line contents for each line of test code. For example code:

```
       L = [spawn(mod, loop, [0]) || _ <- lists:seq(1,10)],
       [H|T] = L,
       PidList = T ++ [self()],
```

I want to transform it to at least something like this:

```
 io:format("Line ~p : ~p",[LineNumber1, LineContent1]),
 L = [spawn(mod, loop, [0]) || _ <- lists:seq(1,10)],
 io:format("Line ~p : ~p",[LineNumber2, LineContent2]),
 [H|T] = L,
 io:format("Line ~p : ~p",[LineNumber3, LineContent3]),
 PidList = T ++ [self()],
```

Ideally it would also print the value of every variable in testcase.

**Question**:
Is this proper way to get more information about whereabouts of bug in test code? If so, which programming language or tool should I use to achieve this effect?

Comment: Do you have eunit tests as well? Maybe EUnit is a better tool for achieving what you want? Usually with a unit test you try to tie down a particular case with specific input and expected output, and the eunit test comparison macros will dump out exactly which expression on which test and line didn't meet expectations, etc, thus you immediately know what failed and assuming it is a side effect free test you probably know EXACTLY what is broken and can reproduce it instantly.

Comment: It's good idea, but not doable - tests are not unit tests, besides rewriting them would take way too much time.

Comment: Unit tests and system tests really have quite different purposes, don't rewrite your system tests as unit tests, just start adding unit tests over time. At some point, it will pay dividends.

Comment: You don't need to run all the test suites with tracing enabled all the time. Hopefully, your test failures are repeatable, and in that case, when a test fails (and only then) do you rerun that test case with tracing or other instrumentation enabled to find out more.

Comment: I agree, I don't want to run whole suites with all tracing all the time. I need to generate tracing code for those cases when testcase repeatedly fails and we need to find out where exactly it fails.